# What is the best practice to generate HTML from dynamic array in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2. Normally we loop through array using *ngFor and show HTML based on the values from array. For example

```
<ul *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    <li>{{employee.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

this works perfectly. But whenever we add elements to that array ( even 1 element ) it will go through whole array to display the HTML. right ?

I wanted to use infinity scroll plugin ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll ) it is working and whenever scroll trigger, elements are added to array and this whole array is looped from the beginning to generate the HTML. I dont think this is a best practice since whenever scroll trigger it will go through whole array to display the HTML.

Ideally the element from particular scroll should append to the existing HTML rather than looping whole array again and again right ?

please help me with some sample code.

Comment: Angular is smart and will do the right thing. That's what "diffing" is about. If necessary, you can help it out by using `trackBy`.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should trigger the service call to fetch the next array elements when user scrolled to the end of the page using below,

```ts
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
         //raise the service call to fetch next set of array elements
    }
};
```

Note: If you need some demo, update code to your post so  that I can reuse it

Comment: i just checked the code from the plugin it self, check the demo of https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll file "app.ts"... here values are pushed to array and render whole array every time

Comment: @user2609021 actually what is your expectation??

Comment: my question is, whenever we add element to array we have to render the HTML by looping the whole array. Will this cause any performance issue ? There should be a better way in Angular 2...

Comment: No it will not cause any performance issue. as the bindings are updated as soon as the values are changed

Comment: @user2609021 did I answer your quesiton?